# Flutter linux build error A required package was not found

Tags: linux, flutter

I get this error when i run  Flutter run -d linux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C77iQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the flutter SDK? I had trouble setting it up manually (i.e. when using the zip download and installing the individual packages). In the end I found it worked best to just [install it using snap](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux) on Kubuntu.

[image: Flutter on Kubuntu with snap]